# Crear numero de factura en java

Tags: java

Quiero crear un método que me genere un numero de factura.

No lo hago incrementar en la BD porque no es recomendable y he decidido crear un campo char varying donde me almacene o como sumarle 1 a la consulta en postgres.

```
public Cliente numOrden() {

                PreparedStatement ps = null;
                ResultSet rs = null;
                Connection con = getConexionTemporal();
                // Preparamos la consulta
                String sql ="select cli_num from cliente where cli_num=cli_num";
                try {
                    // Traemos los datos de la bd
                    ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                    rs = ps.executeQuery();
                    // Cargamos los resultados
                    if (rs.next()) {
                        Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
                        cliente.setNumeroOrden(rs.getString("cli_num"));
                        return cliente;
                    }

                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                } finally {

                    cerrarObjeto(con);
                    cerrarObjeto(rs);
                    cerrarObjeto(ps);

                }
                return null;

            }
```

El controlador donde muestro el numero de factura:

```
private void cargarOrden(){

        SentenciasSQL registro = new SentenciasSQL();
        Cliente cliente = registro.numOrden();

        txtFactura.setText(cliente.getNumeroOrden());
        System.out.println(cliente.getNumeroOrden());
    }
```

Si me ayudan con alguna idea o como seria fácil quiero que sea 00001 y siga 00002 etc.

Comment: La consulta si te trae los datos correctos?

Comment: la consulta me trae el valor del campo que es 001 pero no se como sumarle 1 para cuando vuelva a registrar me salga 002

Comment: Te deje una respuesta espero te pueda ayudar!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer un **count** a la tabla clientes suponiendo que tienes 2 registros regresaría un numero entero 2 y así le podríamos sumar el valor que sigue +1

Consulta:

```
 SELECT COUNT(cli_num) as cli_num FROM clientes
```

Entonces en tu método en lugar de regresar un objeto de tipo cliente regresas un entero **int**

```
            public int numOrden() {

                PreparedStatement ps = null;
                ResultSet rs = null;
                Connection con = getConexionTemporal();
                // Preparamos la consulta
                String sql ="SELECT COUNT(cli_num) as cli_num FROM clientes";
                try {
                    // Traemos los datos de la bd
                    ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                    rs = ps.executeQuery();
                    // Cargamos los resultados
                    if (rs.next()) {
                        int cliente = rs.getInt("cli_num");
                        return cliente;
                    }

                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                } finally {

                    cerrarObjeto(con);
                    cerrarObjeto(rs);
                    cerrarObjeto(ps);

                }
                return null;

            }
```

Y tu método para para obtener el numero de factura quedaria de la siguiente manera:

```
    private void cargarOrden(){
        //Numero de ceros para rellenar el consecutivo de la factura
        int NUMERO_CEROS = 5;

        SentenciasSQL registro = new SentenciasSQL();
        int cliente = registro.numOrden() + 1;

        numeroConsecutivo = rellenarConCeros(String.valueOf(cliente), NUMERO_CEROS);


        txtFactura.setText(numeroConsecutivo);
        System.out.println(numeroConsecutivo);
    }


    private String rellenarConCeros(String cadena, int numCeros) {
        String ceros = "";

        for (int i = cadena.length(); i < numCeros; i++) {
            ceros += "0";
        }

        return ceros + cadena;
    }
```

Comment: amigo me sale este error.

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name cli_num was not found in this ResultSet.

Comment: Listo ya la edite me falto ponerle el nombre de la columna AS cli_num

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podrias hacer es convertir el numero de `String` a `Integer` para sumarle uno y despues hacer una conversión del Integer al formato que deseas guardar en `BD`, te dejo el siguiente código:

```
//Se recibe como parámetro el número en forma de String que se trae de la consulta.
private String convertirNumero(String numero){
     //Se hace el formato del String.
     DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("00000");
     //Se realiza la convesión del String recibido como parámetro y se le suma 1.
     return format.format(Integer.valueOf(numero) + 1);
}
```

Probando el método:

```
String número = "001";
System.out.println("Conversión: "+convertirNumero(numero));
Salida: Conversión: 00002
```

Adaptandolo a tu código quedaria de la siguiente manera:

```
try {
    // Traemos los datos de la bd
    ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs = ps.executeQuery();
    // Cargamos los resultados
    if (rs.next()) {
        Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
        cliente.setNumeroOrden(this.convertirNumero(rs.getString("cli_num")));
        return cliente;
    }

} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: no me esta sumando

Comment: Que es lo que te trae la consulta? Si te trae un valor del tipo "0001"?

Comment: el campo lo tengo como character varying y esta 0001

Comment: Realiza la siguiente impresión al cuando recorres la consulta de BD `System.out.println("Num Cliente: "+rs.getString("cli_num")));`

Comment: Conectado!.
Num Cliente: 1
0001
Conectado!.
Conectado!.
Num Cliente: 2
0001
aun no me suma que sera.

Comment: Entonces la consulta te trae "2 0001" no "0001"?

Comment: no, me trae cliente 2 y en otra linea
0001

Comment: Ahora intenta imprimiendo en el metodo convertiNumero antes del return System.out.println("Format: " + format.format(Integer.valueOf(numero) + 1));

Comment: Format: 0003 ese si esta sumando

Comment: Todos los valores se incrementaron, entonces el error es al momento de mandar a llamar el método para enviar el valor al txtFactura

Comment: en el metodo int numOrden me sale error en el return cliente y return null

Comment: Es que por la respuesta anterior cambiaste el metodo a `int numOrden`, prueba dejandolo como lo tenias `Cliente numOrden`

Comment: ya lo solucione amigo, le quite  cliente.setNumeroOrden(this.convertirNumero(rs.getString("cli_num")));

por este

int cliente = rs.getInt("cli_num");

y funciono muchas gracias Dios lo bendiga.

Answer (score 0):

Estoy aprendiendo en programar en netBeans y quisiera saber si alguien me podría ayudar. Quiero que cuando yo seleccione un comprobante me genere una serie y numero de factura, es decir en donde dice `SerieNum` (001) y don dice `NumeroCom` (000001) y asi consecutivamente, pero cuando el `NumeroCom` llegue a 9999999 el `SerieNum` se convierta en 002. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

[image: )]